# DNS service to access arbitrary IP address

Tags: domain-name-system

Some time ago I used a DNS service which queried with `something.1.2.3.4.[I don't remember the other parts of the domain]` would answer with `1.2.3.4`.

That was quite useful for Web development because `1.2.3.4` could be replaced with anything and the answer would always be whatever you put in its place.

A similar service exists called `localtest.me` but it only ever returns `127.0.0.1`.

I don't remember the name of the service or if it still exists, does anyone know one which does the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're describing http://xip.io/.

Comment: absolutely, looks like it's not well publicized despite being so useful! Many thanks